# When I nest tabular*, \hline is not long enough, How to solve this?

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[10pt,UTF8,openany]{book}     
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
        \begin{table}[H]
            \caption{Specifying the Type of a Literal}
            \label{tab:specify literal type}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ @{} @{\extracolsep{\fill}} | c | @{}}
                \hline
                \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lll}
                    \multicolumn{3}{ c }{Character and Character String Literals} \\
                     Prefix & Meaning & Type \\
                    u & Unicode16 & char16\_t \\
                    U & Unicode32 & char32\_t \\
                    L & wide character  & wchar\_t \\ 
                    u8 & UTF-8(string literal only) & char \\
                \end{tabular*} \\
                \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} llll }
                    \multicolumn{2}{ c }{Integer Literals}  & \multicolumn{2}{ c }{Floating-Point Literals} \\
                    Suffix & Minimum Type & Suffix & Type \\
                    u or U & unsigned & f or F & float \\
                    l or L & long & l or L & long double \\
                    ll or LL & long long & {} & {} \\
                \end{tabular*} \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular*}              
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you nesting them?

Comment: Suppose I have one cake tin which is 8" in diameter and I have a second cake tin which is also 8" in diameter. What will happen if I try to nest the second inside the first? That's what you are doing here ....

Comment: @cfr  it's the easiest way I think out to make a table like this.

Comment: @cfr i see, so how i can make a table like this?

Comment: Like what? You have a bunch of tables you want a border around. So put them in a box and put a frame around it. You don't need a `tabular` for that. `\fbox` will do the job.

Comment: But whatever you put inside needs to be smaller than `\texwidth`. Hopefully, that's obvious.

Comment: @cfr thx, i think i know how to do it.

Comment: `tabularx` is all about line breaking within cells. As you don't have any linebreaking here I would never use `tabularx`. (You could use `tabular*` to force the table to be full width, but I wouldn't do that either.) The top half of the table would be much easier to read set as a `tabular` it is hard to see the association when the columns are artificially forced apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that you're using `@{}` to suppress whitespace padding at the edges only for the outermost `tabular*` environment, but not for the two inner ones. The total width of the construct ends up being `\textwidth+2\tabcolsep`, as may be verified by running your code and comparing the position of the right-hand vertical line with the position of the page number.

I suggest you (a) omit the two outer vertical lines, (b) set `\tabcolsep` to `0pt`, and (c) provide more visual structure to the headers. Your readers will appreciate the effort -- and will likely spend more time actually absorbing the tabular material...

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,UTF8,openany]{book} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \bottomrule, \cmidrule, & \addlinespace
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % <-- new
\caption{Specifying the Type of a Literal}
\label{tab:specify_literal_type}
%%\centering % <-- not necessary
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c}
\toprule
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lll}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Character and Character String Literals} \\
\cmidrule{1-3}
Prefix & Meaning & Type \\
\cmidrule{1-1} \cmidrule{2-2} \cmidrule{3-3}
u & Unicode16 & char16\_t \\
U & Unicode32 & char32\_t \\
L & wide character  & wchar\_t \\ 
u8 & UTF-8 (string literal only) & char \\
\end{tabular*} \\
\addlinespace
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llll}
\multicolumn{2}{ c }{Integer Literals}  & \multicolumn{2}{ c }{Floating-Point Literals} \\
\cmidrule{1-2} \cmidrule{3-4}
Suffix   & Minimum Type & Suffix & Type \\
\cmidrule{1-1} \cmidrule{2-2} \cmidrule{3-3} \cmidrule{4-4}
u or U   & unsigned     & f or F & float \\
l or L   & long         & l or L & long double \\
ll or LL & long long    &        & \\
\end{tabular*} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}  
\end{table}

\end{document}
```